# Удалить методы toString() при обфускации Proguard'ом

Tags: java, proguard

Необходимо удалить методы `toString()` в некоторых классах при обфускации кода Proguard'ом.

Пробовал так:

```
-assumenosideeffects class ** implements com.company.bean.BeanObject {
    public java.lang.String toString();
}
```

, но не помогло.